# Inconsistent partition size

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, zorin

I have a 1tb SSD and Windows 11 installed on it. I wanted to make a dual boot with Zorin, then I created a tiny 40gb partition for it. Some moments later, I realised 40gb wasnt enough, so I tried to expand it to nearly 200gb by reducing the size of the partition with Windows.

I did that from the Zorin OS. The resizing process was in its final steps, I guess, and I saw that the 960gb (Windows) was reduced but there was no 200gb partition there and it was asking for my password to proceed. But my OS froze and the only thing working was the mouse, but it wasnt clicking. I waited some moments and nothing happened, then I shut down my pc.

When I booted it again, there was no 200gb partition but the one with Windows was reduced.

Windows with nearly 700gb:
[image: Windows with nearly 700gb]

Native disk management from Windows:
[image: Native disk management from Windows]

I tried to use the disk management from Windows to reduce the size of the partition, but it gave an error, which I dont remember exactly what it was, except it was saying something about the `chkdsk` command, which I already fixed.

I would like to either create the 200gb partition (I believe it is there, as the Windows partition was reduced) or back the Windows partition to as it was before I attempted to create a partition

Comment: You should add an answer as an answer (even if it's you own), not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

682 is the size of the *file system*. 913 GB is the size of the *partition*.

Probably using a disk editor like DMDE or TestDisk you can 'recover' the 682GB file system. Perhaps there's other tools too. You basically delete the 913 GB partition and insert a 682 partition in it's place.

It's consistent with the story the resize did not complete, file system appears to be resized, then as a final step the partition itself need to be resized, but that never materialized.

Step by setup instruction depend on the tool you'd be using and would need to be given by someone familiar with that tool.

However, it sounds as if the file system is corrupt now. It is unlikely any amount of resizing back to the way it was will fix that. Do you have backup?

It often appears as if people are not aware of the danger that's involved with such resize operations.

Comment: "However, it sounds as if the file system is corrupt now. It is unlikely any amount of resizing back to the way it was will fix that. Do you have backup?"
Yes, I have a backup with my important data. So, should I delete everything (partition) and start from scratch?

Comment: Well, you can attempt repair but it's hard to determine what's exactly going on and what exact file system damage. Theoretically you can edit partition table to size partition down to file system, or edit boot sector to increase size file system (and then run chkdsk to update $bitmap and such). If you have a backup that seems to be most straight forward and certain approach.