# How to mount possibly corrupt .img file

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk-image

While I was waiting for answers on [this post](https://superuser.com/q/1806788/1839132), I tried to fix it by myself.
Basically, I had an 1tb SSD with a dual boot of Windows and Zorin. The Windows partition was NTFS and the Zorin I believe it was ext4. I ran some commands I didnt know what they do (worst mistake) and I ended up by erasing all my partitions (I recommend seeing my previous post).

I heard about `ddrescue` that it may recover some data and I ran it. I followed [this](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/file-recovery/ddrescue-ubuntu.html) tutorial on how to run it and I followed the step 5, specifically. I specified the output .img file to be in an 1tb HD I have, but it already had some backup and the .img couldnt finish to store all of the SSD's 1tb data.

I believe, tough, that it saved most of my data, as the final file has 854gb
and my data in the SSD had 682gb.

I tried to mount the .img file, but without success, as it didnt finish to copy the data.
Some commands I tried to run, but without success:

1. [mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGQSa.png)
2. [kpartx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22NSN.png)
3. [partx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ps7.png)

I would like to open the .img and recover my data

Comment: `ddrescue` does not understand filesystems. If the SSD is 1TB then a full image of it will be 1TB, regardless of the total size of files in the filesystem(s). The image may be sparse and then it may or may not take significantly less space; but the tutorial does not include `ddrescue` commands that create sparse images. Your image is partial, it's not the best you can do, working with it is a waste of time. It also seems you misunderstood the point of `ddrescue` in the first place. `ddrescue` is a tool to … (contn'd)

Comment: (contn'd) … to clone a disk or so. You use it in case the disk is (partially) faulty on the hardware level; the tool tries to read as many sectors as possible and then you can work with the image without any risk of making things worse due to the disk dying in the process. Or you use it to get a copy of a healthy disk, so you can try other tools and attempts-to-fix on the original (or another copy) and in case of failure you have an intact copy, so you can start over. *If* the disk is healthy you can as well use `cp` to get a copy. Neither `ddrescue` nor `cp` alone will … (contn'd).

Comment: (contn'd) … will repair a filesystem or make missing files appear. The copy will be at most as good as the original itself, so if the original filesystem needs to be repaired or if some file recovery tool that understands filesystems may be able to recover some files from the original, then you can as well do this by working on a perfect copy. The sole act of making the copy is not enough. And your current copy is incomplete and thus far from perfect, so it cannot be used to start over in case you mangle the original further.

Comment: To recover use something like DMDE. Recovering a from a corrupt file system is what it is, doesn't matter if it's on a drive or inside an image file.

Answer (score 2):

It was already clear the file system was damaged before you imaged it. Imaging or 'cloning' a damaged file system will not repair a damaged file system, it will just copy it, everything sector-by-sector including all logical errors. If you can not mount the file system before imaging it, it will not mount after it either.

The one exception being, that in some situations bad sectors may hamper mounting, and once the file system is imaged and bad sectors are no longer an issue, the cloned file system *may* be mountable.

If you can not mount the original nor the disk image due to logical corruption, you need to use a tool that was designed to work with damaged file systems to extract the data (folder/files). An example of such a tool is DMDE, chance of success depends on amount of file system corruption.

Just like ddrescue is designed to work around read errors and copy as much of the good sectors as possible, a file recovery tool like DMDE is designed to ignore logical errors and work with file system meta data that's still intact and usable. So a very simplified way to explain data recovery is that we ignore or discard that what is 'broken' somehow and use that what is still intact.

DMDE is just one example, there are plenty others, and now that you have a disk image, you have all the time in the World to find the tool that does best.

Comment: I didnt finish to run DMDE (63%) but I can already see some files. When I finish I will back here and tell what happened